# How to remove the current function from the overload set?

Tags: c++, argument-dependent-lookup

I have a function in my namespace, `ns::foo`, whose job is to dispatch an invocation of `foo` using argument-dependent lookup:

```
namespace ns
{

template<typename T>
void foo(T x)
{
  // call foo through ADL
  foo(x);
}

}
```

I want clients to be able to call `foo` without having to manually instantiate it, i.e.:

```
bar x;
ns::foo(x);
```

Not

```
ns::foo<bar>(x);
```

The problem of course is that `ns::foo` is recursive if there is no better match for `foo` than `ns::foo`.

I don't wish to give `ns::foo` a different name, so is there any way to remove it from the overload set inside itself?

Comment: You could give it a different name, e.g. `fooHelper()`, also `foo(...)` matches everything and is considered before templated function resolution

Comment: Could you post a sample of the original `foo` function that has to be called. If I simply define a `void foo(S s)` I don't get a recursion, because it it a better match than a template.

Comment: @rodrigo - My mistake. It recurses when no better match exists (i.e., when there is no `void foo(S s)`. I'd need a compiler error to occur. I didn't specify that in the question so I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `foo` to where you want to dispatch is not in the `ns` namespace, then this should work:

```
namespace helper
{
    template<typename T>
    void _foo(T x)
    {
        // call foo through ADL
        foo(x);
    }
}

namespace ns
{
    template<typename T>
    void foo(T x)
    {
      ::helper::_foo(x);
    }
}
```

The trick is that the call to `foo` from `_foo` will not consider `ns::foo`, because it is not in an argument-dependent namespace. Unless the type of `x` happens to be in `ns` of course, but then you *have* a recursion by definition.

**UPDATE**: You have to put this code just *after* the definition of `namespace ns`:

```
namespace ns
{
     //your useful stuff here
}
namespace helper { /* template _foo */ }
namespace ns { /* template foo */ }
```

There is no recursion because the `helper::_foo` function cannot call the `template foo` because it is still not defined.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, in my program, the type of `X` does happen to be in `ns`.

Comment: But then your dispatched `foo` function will always collide with your templated one. If you really need this, maybe you should consider a good old macro: `#define foo _foo` in the right place of the header file should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

If you define your ADL functions with an extra argument, it gives it a different type signature, so you won't have a conflict. I defined the template in global scope, but it will work in the `ns` scope as well.

```
namespace ns
{
   class A {};
   class B {};
   void foo(A, int) { std::cout << "adl: fooA" << std::endl; }
   void foo(B, int) { std::cout << "adl: fooB" << std::endl; }
}

template <typename T>
void foo(T t) {
   foo(t, 0);
}

int main()
{
   ns::A a;
   ns::B b;
   foo(a);    //calls ns::foo
   foo(b);    //calls ns::foo
}
```

Comment: That's true, but unfortunately I'm in a situation where I don't have control over the signature of the function of interest.

Comment: @JaredHoberock: Can you add the argument to the template function instead? Or are you trying to intercept existing calls and do something extra?

Comment: Yes, I could decorate `ns::foo` in some manner, perhaps with an `enable_if`, or some other decorator around its parameter.

Comment: @JaredHoberock: I agree rodrigo's answer is better. +1 on your question from me too.